# Tree traversal without recursive / stack usage (C#)?

Tags: performance, stack, tree-traversal

I'm working with WPF and I'm developing a complex usercontrol, which is composed of a tree with rich functionality etc.
For this purpose I used a View-Model design pattern, because some operations couldn't be achieved directly in WPF. So I take the IHierarchyItem (which is a node and pass it to this constructor to create a tree structure)

```
private IHierarchyItemViewModel(IHierarchyItem hierarchyItem, IHierarchyItemViewModel parent)
        {
            this.hierarchyItem = hierarchyItem;
            this.parent = parent;    

            List<IHierarchyItemViewModel> l = new List<IHierarchyItemViewModel>();
            foreach (IHierarchyItem item in hierarchyItem.Children)
            {
                l.Add(new IHierarchyItemViewModel(item, this));
            }
            children = new ReadOnlyCollection<IHierarchyItemViewModel>(l);
        }
```

The problem is that this constructor takes about 3 seconds !! for 200 items on my dual-core.
Am I doing anythig wrong or recursive constructor call is that slow?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Ok everything above is correct. The problem resided in hierarchyItem.Children as it took too long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be nothing wrong with a recursive implementation of a tree, especially for such a small number of items.  A recursive implementation is sometimes less space efficient, and slightly less time efficient, but the code clarity often makes up for it.

It would be useful for you to perform some simple profiling on your constructor.  Using one of the suggestions from: http://en.csharp-online.net/Measure_execution_time you could indicate for yourself how long each piece is taking.

There is a possibility that one piece in particular is taking a long time.  In any case, that might help you narrow down where you are really spending the time.

Comment: Thank you, I'm gonna try that snippet.. You are probably right, it cannot take that longer, problem might be somewhere in particular item.

Comment: int this line :foreach (IHierarchyItem item in hierarchyItem.Children)
hierarchyItem.Children took too long.

Answer (score 4):

OK I found a non recursive version by myself, although it uses the Stack.
It traverses the whole tree:

```
Stack<MyItem> stack = new Stack<MyItem>();

stack.Push(root);

while (stack.Count > 0)
{
    MyItem taken = stack.Pop();

    foreach (MyItem child in taken.Children)                
       stack.Push(MyItem);                    

}
```

Comment: Just a small FYI for any googlers: You can use a Queue for a breadth-first traversal if you are so inclined. A stack creates a depth-first traversal.